# Sql (Oracle) -->Sequence does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I got the error message,

Cause: The specified sequence does not exist, or the user does
        not have the required privilege to perform this operation.

*Action:   Make sure the sequence name is correct, and that you have
           the right to perform the desired operation on this sequence.

The player table is

```
CREATE TABLE player (
    playno           NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    playname         VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    protectmedalno   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    mastermedalno    CHAR(10)
);
```

primary key is playno.

The protector table is

```
CREATE TABLE protector (
    protectmedalno   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    protectname      VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL   
);
```

primary key is protectmedalno

I want to use playno_seq to generate a playno automatically. Let Snow has the protector Owl.

When debugging, I got some error message, such as "too many values". Now I got the message"sequence does not exist."

```
CREATE SEQUENCE playno_seq
START WITH     100
INCREMENT BY   1
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;

DROP SEQUENCE playno_seq;

INSERT INTO protector VALUES ('109','Owl');
COMMIT;

INSERT INTO player VALUES (playno_seq.nextval, ‘Snow’,’109’,null);
```

Comment: Why do you `DROP SEQUENCE playno_seq;` before using it? If you drop it, it does not exists any more, so you certainly have the error!

Comment: I misunderstood "drop" ><"

Comment: It worked ! Thank you~

Comment: Then search for it. `DROP` mean you delete all object value, and object definition, compare to `DELETE` often only delete object value. In this case `object` means your sequence.